# json.loads UnicodeEncodeError

Tags: python-3.x, beautiful-soup, json-encode

Выдает ошибку UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 138-140: ordinal not in range(128)
Она возникает в строке  encoded = fetch(requestURL)

Я пробовала добавлять .encode('ascii'), но это не помогло

```
import urllib3
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import json


url = "https://www.tripadvisor.ru/Attractions-g60763-Activities-New_York_City_New_York.html"



def fetch(url):
    http = urllib3.PoolManager()
    r = http.request('GET', url)
    data = r.data
    return data 

def extract_data(data):
    #locate link to attraction page
    baseUrl = "https://www.tripadvisor.ru"
    website = baseUrl + data.findChildren('a')[0]['href']
    coords = extract_address(website)

    print("waiting 1 sec...")
    time.sleep(1)

    name = data.findChildren('a')[0].string.strip()
    numReviews = data.findChildren('span', 'more')[0].findChildren('a')[0].string.strip()


    print ("site name: " + name) 
    print ("number of reviews: " + numReviews) 
    print ('-------')

    return name + " | " + numReviews + "|" + str(coords['lat']) + "|" + str(coords['lng']) + "\n"

#function to open attraction page and extract adress
def extract_address(r):
    print("opening attraction page: " + r)
    page = fetch (r)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

    #parse HTML for address components
    try:
        street = soup.findAll('span',"street-address")[0].string.strip()
    except Exception as e:
        street = ""

    try:
        extended_address = soup.findAll('span', 'extended-address')[0].string.strip()
    except Exception as e:
        extended_address = ""

    try:
        locality = soup.findAll('span',"locality")[0].string.strip()
    except Exception as e:
        locality = ""

    #generate request URL from components
    requestURL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="+street+" "+extended_address+" "+locality+"&key=..."
    requestURL = requestURL.replace(" ","%20")
    print(requestURL)
    print ("address: "+street+" "+extended_address+" "+locality)



    encoded = fetch(requestURL)
    decoded = json.loads(encoded)


    try:
        coords = decoded['results'][0]['geometry']['location']
    except Exception as e:
        coords = {"lat" : 0,"lng" : 0}

    print (coords)
    return coords      

def fetch_items(url):
    page = fetch(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
    listing = soup.findAll('div', 'attraction_element')

    entry = ""
    for s in listing:
        entry += extract_data(s)

    f.write(entry)

    print("waiting 1 sec...")
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос полный текст ошибки, с трэйсбэком.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том, что в URL передаются кириллические символы без кодирования.

Импортируйте

```
from urllib.parse import quote_plus
```

и замените

```
requestURL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="+street+" "+extended_address+" "+locality+"&key=..."
requestURL = requestURL.replace(" ","%20")
```

на

```
requestURL = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' + quote_plus(street + ' ' + extended_address + ' ' + locality + '&key=...')
```

P.S. У вас ещё и переменная `f` не инициализирована в функции `fetch_items`.

Comment: Sergey Gornostaev,  при такой замене неправильно формируется код запроса страницы

в итоге
получается


{
   "error_message" : "You must use an API key to authenticate each request to Google Maps Platform APIs. For additional information, please refer to http://g.co/dev/maps-no-account",
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}

Comment: @AlfiyaShakuryanova у меня ваш скрипт отработал без проблем. Судя по ошибке, ему что-то не нравится в ключе.

Comment: при неисправленных вот этих двух строках он выдавал вот такую страницу

{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Центральный парк",
               "short_name" : "Центральный парк",
               "types" : [ "establishment", "park", "point_of_interest" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Manhattan",
               "short_name" : "Manhattan"...

Значит, с ключом, все ок должно быть

Comment: Это я просто проверила requestURL в браузере

Comment: @AlfiyaShakuryanova я не могу это повторить, а как следствие и помочь.

Comment: Вот разница в первом и во втором случае в requestURL

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Hudson+River%2C+Piers+59-62+Between+17th+And+23rd+Streets+%D0%9D%D1%8C%D1%8E-%D0%99%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%2C+NY+10011%26key%3D...

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=59th%20to%20110th%20Street%20Manhattan%20Borough,%20from%20Central%20Park%20West%20to%205th%20Avenue%20%D0%9D%D1%8C%D1%8E-%D0%99%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA,%20NY%2010022&key=...

Comment: Да, я понимаю

что делает quote_plus?
Почему так сильно изменилась структура?

Comment: @AlfiyaShakuryanova кодирует строку запроса в [percent-encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).

Comment: ситуация разрешилась, когда я вынесла API ключ за пределы скобок  quote_plus. Видимо, он его тоже менял, поэтому была проблема.
Спасибо большое за вашу помощь!